# Which file to Initialize Database in WPF MVVM Entity Frameworks Code First

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, ef-code-first

[image: WFP MVVM EF Code First Architecture]

I've got about six months experience with WPF/MVVM and am trying to incorporate EF Code First in my project. Two questions:

1. Is the layout in the image above the best to use? Is it better to use sub-projects or would sub-folders work just as well? I'm open to suggestions.
2. Got this code to work in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

   ```
   namespace someNamespace
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
       /// </summary>
       public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
           private EmployeeDBContext context = new EmployeeDBContext();

           public MainWindow()
           {
              InitializeComponent();
              Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EmployeeDBContext>());
           }

           private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource employeeViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("employeeViewSource")));
               context.Employees.Load();
               employeeViewSource.Source = context.Employees.Local;            
           }

           private void Button_Search(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {     
              //event handler code              
              using (var context = new EmployeeDBContext())
              {                      
                 context.Employees.Add(employee);
                 context.SaveChanges();
              }
           }              

           protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
           {
             base.OnClosing(e);
             this.context.Dispose();
           }

           private void Button_Exit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
              this.Close();
           }        
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: So what is the question exactly? If you have normal project structure or not? 
I don't really see a connection to the post title.

Comment: Question #1 is the question. I had a question about #2 previously but got the code above to work so replaced previous code (of which I had a question) with new code. Wondering though if this code needs to go in my ViewModel.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sub-folders or projects makes little difference. If you have separate projects you can build them one at a time - a bit faster. 
   2. I'm pretty new to MVVM too but I do know that you should keep code-behind to a minimum. What you wrote there should be done using RelayCommands. Also you wouldn't call the dbContext from the ViewModel. The ViewModel talks to a Dataservice which manages the dbContext.
   Not sure what the title means. Are you asking where to put your ADONet Entity Data Model?

Comment: Could you provide an example how a/the VM class would talk to a/the DataService (class?) which in turn would interact with the dbContext if I wanted to populate a drop menu (in the View) with an employee name from an Employee table with columns Emp_ID, Name, and Title? (BTW, never mind the title; related to a previous question which is irrelevant). Thanks.